# Special type of Hadamard matrix or vector that orthogonal with all its cyclic shifts

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I would like to investigate all positive integers $n$ such that there exist Hadamard matrix 
$$
H=a_0+a_1S+a_2S^2+\cdots+a_{n-1}S^{n-1},
$$
where $a_i\in\{-1,1\}$ and 
$$
S=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots  & \vdots & & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0  & \cdots & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

In other words, we have vector $v_1=(a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_{n-1})\in \{-1,1\}^n$ and all its cyclic shifts $v_2$, $v_3$, $\ldots$, $v_n$. It is known that for any $i\neq j$ vectors $v_i$ and $v_j$ are orthogonal.

It is easy to see that $n$ must equals $4k^2$ for some $k$. In fact, 
$$
(a_0+a_1+\ldots+a_{n-1})^2=(a_0^2+a_1^2+\cdots+a_{n-1}^2) + \bigl((a_0a_1+a_1a_2+\cdots+a_{n-1}a_0)+\\
{}+(a_0a_2+a_1a_3+\cdots+a_{n-1}a_1)+\cdots+(a_0a_{n-1}+a_1 a_0+\cdots+ a_{n-1} a_{n-2})\bigr)=n
$$
Since $n$ is obviously even we are done.

When $n=4$ vector $v_1=(1,1,1,-1)$ gives the example.

When $n=4k^2$, $k>1$ the only thing I know that $\#\{i\colon a_i=1\}=2k^2+k$ and $\#\{i\colon a_i=-1\}=2k^2-k$. 
In some literature I saw that for $n=16$ there is no example,

Any ideas?

Comment: The keyword here is *circulant*.  Searching for "circulant Hadamard matrix" yields this survey note by Richard Stanley, which mentions that it is conjectured (but not known) that $n=4$ is the only example: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-318-topics-in-algebraic-combinatorics-spring-2006/lecture-notes/hadamard.pdf

Comment: The state of the art on this problem as of 2002 is given in Bernhard Schmidt's [book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540442431).  There is some more recent work, described in [this MathOverflow answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/140185).